# HashiCorp Vault Create User to Login on AWS Management Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, hashicorp-vault

I´m using hashicorp vaul with AWS secrets engine to create temporary users on aws.

Using this example bellow of iam role is possible create a user.

```
    vault write aws/roles/my-role \
    credential_type=iam_user \
    policy_document=-<<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This will be create a user on aws.

```
 vault read aws/creds/my-role
Key                Value
---                -----
lease_id           aws/creds/my-role/f3e92392-7d9c-09c8-c921-575d62fe80d8
lease_duration     768h
lease_renewable    true
access_key         AKIAIOWQXTLW36DV7IEA
secret_key         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
security_token     <nil>
```

The problem is, after this users was created is not possible login on AWS Management Console, because this user is only to user on aws cli, boto3 for example.

Is possible create a user using vault to logon on aws management console ?
How do it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, your only option is a custom plugin.